# My signals stopped working after extending my default user model using BaseUserAdmin

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, django-signals, django-users

I had a working signal that creates a new profile when a new user is created, but i wanted to extend the users as either teacher, parent, or Admin, then it stopped working.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
from phone_field import PhoneField


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to = 'profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 600 or img.width > 600:
            output_size = (600,600)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)



class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.last_name, self.first_name)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile, Student, Teacher, Parent
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ParentInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Parent
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'parent'

class TeacherInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Teacher
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'teacher'


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (ParentInLine, TeacherInLine)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

admin.site.register(Profile)
admin.site.register(Teacher)
admin.site.register(Parent)
```

Signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(User = instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

There are no errors, but i just cant let it automatically create a profile for whenever a new user is created.
Is there something i am doing wrong? Or something that i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem. What I did was editing my "create_profile" function.

From:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(User = instance)
```

To:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

Then I added in my

**init.py**

```
default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'
```

Then it started working. I've been stuck with this particular problem for 4 days and I am basically a newbie with 2 to 3 weeks of django experience. Hope this will help others if you come upon the same problem.